# Link for sharing a post doesn't fit inside a block

Tags: bug, design, sharing

Tapping on share link under any post opens popup block with text:

> [image: share]

Sometimes field's width is not enough for whole link as showed on the picture above. Actual [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286504/339911) is:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286504/339911
```

Tested on iPad with Chrome and Safari browsers.

For main (not Meta) sites like *Stack Overflow*, *Server Fault*, *Super User* etc width of sharing block is enough for link length. On this basis, I have decided that the width of block was initially chosen to show **entire** link (in partucular `q` is used instead of `question`). If for another sites width is not enough - it should be increased for consistency. Probably the best solution should be to use uniform short link for all *Stack Exchange* sites (like `goo.gl`, `bit.ly` etc).

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a official link to quote, but AFAIK that's a status-by-design.

The usage is to *"share"* the link via the social buttons, or least, to *"copy"* the link (*<kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will do, the link is already highlighted*). None of this explicitly require the whole link text to be *visible*.

---

EDIT:

Not only MSE, all meta sites exhibit the same scenario, more or less. Moreover there's no *standard* width for the sitenames, either. So, for a newer site, which may have a longer name, the problem would re-arrive.

That said, third-party URL shorteners are not allowed. Implementing an in-house URL shortener would be *too much effort* to solve a problem that many would not even consider a problem, at all. Just my opinion, though.

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: @alexolut All the meta has the same behaviour. :)

Comment: BTW, auto highlighting is not working in iOS.

Comment: I said about Meta sites in question. I think it's an oversight.

Comment: @alexolut Not really, poor choice of words from my end, maybe. I wanted to stress on " _all_ ...  _same behaviour._ ".

Comment: It's not just meta sites, lots of sites have subdomains long enough to cause the Overflow

Comment: @Cai but Overflow is not occurs for Stack Overflow. Strange as it may sound.